# Include Common Node in Multiple .launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a set of launch files that each of them initiate a subsystem. However, some of the .launch files contain dependencies on a subset of the system. I could include all dependencies in a .launch file and include it in all other launch files. However, for running the complete system, I include all .launch files in a "global" launcher. This causes the common nodes to start multiple times. How could I solve that? Is there any way to "declare once" some nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10540/include-common-node-in-multiple-.launch/) by [miltos](https://answers.ros.org/users/559/miltos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way would be to give each of your subsystem launch files an argument (which could default to `true`) and use the `if` attribute within those launch files to start your common nodes only when that argument is set to `true`. Then, in your global launcher, set the same argument to `false` when you include the subsystem launch files and launch the common nodes once.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3